# ftp steam directory uploading permission denied

Tags: xubuntu, steam, ftp

I have ubuntu installed on my vps. I installed steam on it and I am trying to make asseto corsa server (racing game). It worked but now when i want to upload files into steam or game directory it doesnt work. other directories work fine. Also, i cant edit existing files. Editing through terminal with "sudo" works fine. When trying to upload WinSCP says permission denied. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the files over to `/tmp` with the user you have using WinScp.
Once the files are copied to `/tmp`, you can ssh to the vps using the same user, then copy the file to location of your choice using `sudo cp /tmp/<file> /<locationOfYourChoice>`. You might have to change the permissions of the file to the user of choice using `chmod` AND/OR `chown`.

I would recommend you go through some tutorials in Linux([here's a start](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-manage-file-and-folder-permissions-linux/)) about file permissions and users before attempting to change permissions willy nilly. This will save you from having to do all this from scratch.